# Using head and tail to return the nth item from a file in Linux

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm pretty new to using Linux commands. So suppose I have a file with 100 thousand lines. Well suppose I want to get line 50,000. Is there a way I can give the shell a command to retrieve line 50,000 using head and tail commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
head -n 50000 FILENAME | tail -1
```

That should work. However this may not be the most efficient way of accessing the 50000th line

Answer (score 4):

The above examples can work, but there are other ways, like `sed` for example:

```
% sed -n '50000p' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
head -n 50000 file_name  | tail -n 1
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

```
head -[linenumber] file | tail -1
```